# How to retrieve absolute position of child sprite (that is child of a parent sprite) in Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have two parent sprites.

Each parent has two children sprites.

Although the two parent sprites have different positions, it seems that the position of the child sprites for both parents are identical.

What I mean is, although the children are attached to the parent, and visually appear to move wherever the parents move, the point value of the "position" property remains the same.

When you move the parents around the screen, you can see the children moving too. There position really does change.

But the "position" property of the children always remains the same.

What am I doing wrong? How can I retrieve the absolute position of the child sprite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get one child's absolute position, relative to the screen (or more accurately the scene), use this:

```
CGPoint absolutePosition = [childSprite convertToWorldSpace:childSprite.position];
```

I don't think you were doing anything wrong.  A child's position is relative to its parent so it makes sense that the children's positions are not changing.

Comment: Interesting how would you go about detecting collision with a sprite child ?

Comment: @AlexanderN Could you use CGRectIntersectsRect(a, b)? I think it will get tricky quickly though with non-rectangular content.